# Vertex Attribute Arrays\not receiving vertex data in LWJGL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Cannot seem to get Vertex Attribute Arrays working properly for per vertex data.

Here's the SSCCE:

```
private static void createDisplay(int w, int h) {
    try {
        Display.create();
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(w, h));
    }
    catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    float size = 1;
    float aspect = (float) Display.getWidth() / Display.getHeight();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(-size * aspect, size * aspect, -size, size, -1, 1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    createDisplay(1200, 800);
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

    ShaderManager.createShader("2Dv", new File("src/Shaders/2D.vert"), SHADER_VERT);
    ShaderManager.createShader("2Df", new File("src/Shaders/2D.frag"), SHADER_FRAG);
    ShaderManager.createProgram("2D", "2Dv", "2Df");
    // Shader compiles and links correctly.
    ShaderManager.useProgram("2D");
    // Calls glUseProgram(programID);

    float[] vertexData = new float[] {-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f};

    int vao = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
    if (vao == 0)
        System.exit(-1);
    GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
    int vertexBuffer = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtil.asDirectFloatBuffer(vertexData), GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    // GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // GL11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 2 * 4, 0);

    int loc = ShaderManager.currentProgram.getAttribute("vertex");
    if (loc == -1)
        Debug.log(Debug.INSTANCE_MANAGEMENT, "Attribute [", "", "] not found in Shader [",
                ShaderManager.currentProgram.toString(), "].");
    else {
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GLCONST.TYPE_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, 0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
    }

    GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

    GL11.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1);

    int indexBuffer = GL15.glGenBuffers();
    GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
    GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, BufferUtil.asDirectFloatBuffer(new float[] {0, 1, 2, 3}),
            GL15.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vao);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_QUADS, 4, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        Display.update();
        int error = GL11.glGetError();
        if (error != GL11.GL_NO_ERROR)
            System.out.println(GLU.gluErrorString(error));
    }

}
```

The problem lies in the usage of vertex Attribute arrays. The old code I used was:

```
GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
GL11.glVertexPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 2 * 4, 0);
```

The new version is:

```
int loc = ShaderManager.currentProgram.getAttribute("vertex");//Call to glGetAttribLocation();
if (loc == -1){
    System.exit(-1);
}
GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(loc, 2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 2 * 4, 0);
GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(loc);
```

The original code was the commented 2 lines. Upon running, this correctly sent vertex data to gl_Vertex and rendered a square of size 1.

The new code shuld send vertex data to the vertex attribute, but it gets nothing.

When the original code is uncommented and both old and new code used, both gl_Vertex and vertex attribute get vertex data.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the problem after a while. The problem is due to an AMD driver bug when using a OpenGL 3.0+ core profile.

The "vertex" attribute array was assigned a location of 1.

The bug occurs when the attribute array 0 is unused. Nothing is rendered if array 0 is not enabled.

To fix this probelm I simply explicitly assigned "vertex" to location 0.

`layout(location = 0) in vec4 vertex;`